# postInstallScript is not inserting CustomSettings after installing managed package

Tags: managed-package, integration, postinstall

I have below post install script class which is used to insert a demo login details for our application.

```
global class PostInstallClass implements InstallHandler {
    global void onInstall(InstallContext context) {
        if(context.previousVersion() == null) {
            ns__config__c info = new ns__config__c(); //Private Custom Setting.
            info.ns__jwtToken__c = '';
            info.Name = 'loginUserName';
            info.ns__password__c = 'Admin123';
            info.ns__eSign_Url__c = 'https://domain.ourapplication.com/';
            info.ns__domain__c = 'domain';
            insert info;
            ns__testCustom__c test = ns__testCustom__c.getOrgDefaults();//public custom setting.
            test.ns__testName__c = 'test user';
            insert test;
        }
    }
}
```

I did added this class to managed package POST INSTALL SCRIPT. To test if is working, I have added normal public custom setting and inserted it. Seems like it's not getting executed at all. am I missing anything?? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: pls use `{}` to format the code

Answer (score 1):

You are using `context.previousVersion() == null` it means code will execute only first installation This will not work for the Upgraded package.

If the issue is coming for the first installation then use the try-catch block and send the Mail from the catch that will the to identify the error.